# tcolorbox disable blank option

Tags: tcolorbox, documentation

While writing a package I started to use `tcolorbox` and its `documentation` library. I found the keys `doc head command` etc. and started to customize. But there are strong limitations to that, because I basically cannot use the `enhanced` features. The reason (code from the package):

```
\newtcolorbox{tcb@doc@head}[1]{blank,colback=white,colframe=white,
  code={\tcbdimto\tcb@temp@grow@left{-\kvtcb@doc@indentleft}%
        \tcbdimto\tcb@temp@grow@right{-\kvtcb@doc@indentright}},
  grow to left by=\tcb@temp@grow@left,%
  grow to right by=\tcb@temp@grow@right,
  sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
  sidebyside gap=-\tcb@w@upper@real,
  phantom=\phantomsection,%
  enlarge bottom by=-0.2\baselineskip,#1}
```

It contains the option `blank` which disables all drawing. For customization purposes I would like to remove it. Do I really have to redefine the whole command or is there any easy way?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}
\tcbset{
doc head command={colback=black} % disable blank here for the fancy stuff
}

\begin{document}
\begin{docCommand}{examplecommand}
Test
\end{docCommand}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\tcbset{blank/.style={}}`  just after loading the `documentation` library?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Simple, but effective. I hope this does not break anything. Would you mind writing up an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to say `\tcbset{blank/.style={}}` after loading the `documentation` library, but this could break other `tcolorbox` environments (their look would change if `blank` is used there).

Another solution is to define `noblank` which partially revokes the definitions in `blank` (see the file `tcbskins.code.tex` for the settings), unfortunately, some of the options have to copied over and changed manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\tcbuselibrary{documentation}


% From tcbskins.code.tex
% blank/.style={enhanced,frame hidden,interior hidden,segmentation hidden,%
%    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxsep=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,boxrule=0pt,%
%    bottomtitle=6pt,middle=3pt}}

\tcbset{
  noblank/.style={enhanced,frame style={draw,fill=tcbcol@frame}, interior style={draw,fill=tcbcol@back}, segmentation hidden,sharp corners,
    %boxrule=1pt, % Change at will
    %boxsep=1pt,
  }
}

\tcbset{
  doc head command={colback=black,noblank} % disable blank here for the fancy stuff
}




\begin{document}
\begin{docCommand}{examplecommand}{}
Test
\end{docCommand}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TeXnician: Change the options at will. I think the `segmentation hidden` style is crucial for the `documentation` commands, that's why I did not reenable  it

Comment: To revoke the `frame hidden` from `blank` I suggest to use `frame style=` (note the `=`) instead of `frame style={draw,fill=tcbcol@frame}` for `noblank`. The same goes for `interior style` :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm: I did not think of that easy way. I'll give it a try